# Loading Jinja2 Directory For Whole App

Tags: python, jinja2

I currently load my template directory at the beginning of the **main_app**:

```
import blog
import jinja2
import os
import re
import registration
import webapp2
from string import letters

#   loads templates to make our life easier
template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir),
                               autoescape = True)

########    Main App Function   ########
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([ ('/', blog.WelcomePage),
                                ('/blog/?', blog.BlogFront), 
                                ('/blog/([0-9]+)', blog.PostPage), 
                                ('/blog/newpost', blog.NewPost),
                                ('/register', registration.RegistrationPage)
                                ], 
                                debug=True)
```

However I obviously need access to my HTML files in other classes, for example, in **registration.py**:

```
class Login(mainhandler.MainHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render('login-form.html')
```

If there one place where I can place the bit of code:

```
 #  loads templates to make our life easier
    template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
    jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir),
                                   autoescape = True)
```

to allow for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a basehandler to do all the rendering and use Python inheritance to access the handler in a very easy way.

See this article from Nick Johnson: http://blog.notdot.net/2011/11/Migrating-to-Python-2-7-part-2-Webapp-and-templates

Comment: Thanks man, Python is completely new to me. I'm not sure I like the whole trusting of whitespaces thing...